# callback-method like Options in kubernetes API

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have been working on kubernetes REST API calls to create deployments and services using python client. Now the scenario is that i have to create deployment and when the pods get ready i have to tell users that their deployment is ready using some callback method. I can achieve this using cli like

```
watch kubectl describe pod <pod-name>
```

and looking into pod status.
But how can i implement a call-back function which is called when pod status is changed e.g from `container creating -> ready`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Python Kubernetes Client Library

```
pip install kubernetes

from kubernetes import client, config

def get_pods(name, exact=False, namespace='default'):

    # TODO check if this could be created once in an object.
    config.load_kube_config(os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], '.kube/config'))

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()

    pod_list = v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace)

    if exact:
        relevant_pods = [pod for pod in pod_list.items if name == pod.metadata.name]
    else:
        relevant_pods = [pod for pod in pod_list.items if name in pod.metadata.name]

    return relevant_pods
```

You can use Airflow for most use cases

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/06/28/airflow-on-kubernetes-part-1-a-different-kind-of-operator/

I wrote a library which reacts to kubernetes events and more.

It is reactive meaning it is directly opposed to the declarative style of Helm and is a debuggable python deployment tool to replace Helm.

https://github.com/hamshif/Wielder

pip install wielder

To use open source examples

https://github.com/hamshif/wield-services

and in tandem with Apache Airflow

https://github.com/hamshif/dags/tree/6daf6313d35824b58efa7f61f90e30a169946532

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could watch [the events](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/) on the namespace where you are deploying the application, and react to that

> Events such as the ones you saw at the end of `kubectl describe pod` are persisted in etcd and provide high-level information on what is happening in the cluster. To list all events you can use `kubectl get events`

Comment: but can i implement callback to an event instead of continuously watching with kubectl ?